# CentOS 8 doesn't find any disk

Tags: centos, dell-poweredge, raid-10

I need some help about CentOS 8.

I am trying to install CentOS 8 to Dell PowerEdge r715 server with a RAID-10 configured, but when I run the installer, it can not find the disks form the server, but I tried to install CentOS 6 and 7 and it detects the disk and I can install without any problem the iso.

I do not know why is happening someone some help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat 8 removed tons of storage drivers — like sas2 and below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

As you said centos 8 kernel doesn't work with sas disk and i had to install centos 7 and now it works fine,

Hope it helps someone else.

Guillem